# How do I know whether bash kill will use a pid or a jobspec?

Tags: shell, syntax, process, sh, kill

From the fine manual page:

```
kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] [pid | jobspec] ...
kill -l [sigspec | exit_status]
    Send  the  signal  named  by sigspec or signum to the processes named by pid or 
    jobspec.  sigspec is etc. etc....
```

So what decides whether `kill 1` kills the init process or jobspec 1?

Comment: Huh, didn't know kill supported jobspec, I've always used the generic `jobs -x kill %1`

Comment: @bishop don't think it does, I think it's the shell intercepting the `kill` to add that functionality to its job managment.

Comment: @bishop I'm wondering if `jobs -x kill %1;` creates a superfluous process, too. `jobs` is a builtin, but that might actually invoke kill(1) (and bash will substitute the jobspec with the PID so that kill(1) can actually do its job). If you use `kill %1`, `kill` is a builtin so no new process will be run. This is especially useful if you've reached the limit of running processes on a machine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

with kill 1 you will send a signal to process with pid 1. To kill job 1 you have to type

```
  kill %1
```

the jobspec is %

Comment: Is this documented?

Comment: @LimitedAtonement not in the `bash` man page, at least. Strange since that's what one sees in `man jobs`.

Comment: @Walf Thanks! `man jobs` talks about kill(1) taking `%` prefix, but not `man kill`. Now this makes sense to me because if you actually run kill(1), jobspecs won't work! Jobspecs is a bash thing about which kill cannot know. `help kill` says "Kill is a shell builtin for two reasons: it allows job IDs to be used...".

Comment: @LimitedAtonement you must have a newer version of `bash`, I don't see the `jobspec` format definition in either man page.

Comment: @Walf : It seems this is now documented in the bash man page (bash 5.1.4 on Devuan Chimaera) - although not extremely clearly. The `kill` documentation says `pid | jobspec` and the section on job control has the first appearance of the phrase jobspec where it says that a jobspec starts with a `%`.